# Cannot post comments in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

We have made a duplicate of one of our sites, this is the duplicate:
http://test.blog.aias.com.au/

Cannot get the comments to work for anonymous or admin users on the front end of the site. What I mean by that is that if I am admin I can only post comments via the administration interface (writing a comment in the comments section) but not on the fron-end of the website.

What is most bizzare is that the comments work fine on the original site but not on the duplicate site.

In the "Discussion" settings, "Users must be registered and logged in to comment" is tuned off but that still doesn't explain why even admin users cannot post comments via the "Add comment" link on the front-end of the website.

How can I get the Comments to work for the duplicate site?
Is there any back-end configurations files that need changing after doing the deployment to the duplicate website?

thanks,
Andrei

Comment: How did you duplicate the site?

Comment: Are u using diquss, something else?

Comment: A couple other things - the test site doesn't seem to be publicly visible, making it tough for us to troubleshoot.  Also, I can't add a comment on the real site either (assuming it's blog.aias.com.au).

Comment: Ah sorry, try this, same site but production:
http://blog.aias.com.au/

Comment: When moving wordpress sites around, you have to do a lot of find and replace in the sql to point to the correct paths, I'm guessing this is your problem, but it depends on how you duplicated the site

Comment: Christ Herbert - The site had been duplicated via ftp and pointing to its own database.

Comment: the original site (that the comments on) that has been duplicated from is: http://blog.acpe.edu.au/

Comment: It would be better for us to see the test site.

Comment: Why do you have such a URL with "index.php" inside? http://blog.acpe.edu.au/index.php. I can see that this redirects to the root, but not on your test site. So there is some sort of htaccess redirect that does not work the same on both sites

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) once in the wp-admin, in tools you'll see "Search and Replace" type in the old url(original) and replace with the new url..click go and it will replace every single line in your database with the new value.  I've done this with many wordpress sites moving from dev to production.

Comment: You may also want to check to be sure that your theme files don't have any hard-coded paths.